# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: java, mysql

estaba generando las tablas para mi base de datos dbDaca.sql, resulta que tengo el siguiente problema:

[image: error al crear tabla]

sabiendo que mi PRIMARY KEY PARA TODAS MIS TABLAS ES IdColaborador, por eso es que en cada tabla le coloco un references. Ustedes se preguntaran porque le coloco "NroEstudio" , lo que sucede es que un colaborador tiene 1 o mas estudios tecnicos por lo tanto ese campo lo coloque para contabilizar cuantos estudios a realizado y listarlo del 1 a n veces.

- la logica que estoy llevando a cabo es que en mi bd existen 11 tablas, de las 11 tablas todos los campos pertenecen a una persona, y al momento de hacer una consulta solo llamaria con el IdColaborador y me botaria las 11 tablas, es por eso que en cada una solo le coloco el IdColaborador como referencia, ustedes que opinan? o debo crear una PRIMARY KEY Para cada una de mis tablas ? y luego para llamar todaa esa informacion, utilizaria el inner join? Muchas gracias de antemano por su apoyo, saludos.

Comment: El numero de estudio es por paciente o general a toda la base?

Comment: Por colaborador.

Comment: entonces que sea un autonumerico esta mal.. porque autonumerico es general a la tabla (o a la DB)

Comment: Entonces, borro el auto incremet y que el colaborador ponga el nro de estudio? Pero lo de la primary key no hay problema, verdad?

Comment: No conozco tanto tus reglas de negocios como para saber si eso es correcto o no.. En DB hay cosas que dependen de las reglas de negocios. Sin saber de lo que estas hablando (y esto puede inducir a errores) prefiero no decirte si esta bien o mal. no se ni porque tenes 11 tablas y que todas ellas tengan la misma clave principal suena muy raro.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Consulta sobre base de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262967/consulta-sobre-base-de-datos)