# Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla llamada alumnos la cual tiene las siguientes variantes:

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_fenix`.`alumnos` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `rut_alumno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `edad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `clave` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_licencia` INT NULL,
  `id_region` INT NULL,
  `id_sucursal` INT NULL,
  `id_curso` INT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rut_alumno`));
```

Como se ve en `PRIMARY KEY` tengo a `'RUT_ALUMNO'` el cual es como el `DNI` en algunos países, el problema que tengo es que necesito dejar 'ID' como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y no puedo dejar a ambos como `primarykey`

¿por que lo hice?

por que quisiera que el usuario a la hora de buscar el alumno solamente dijite el rut, que el rut sea la forma de manejarse completamente ya que cada alumno tiene un rut único

Comment: ID puede ser AUTO INCTREMENT sin necesidad de ser primary key}

Comment: yo tenia entendido lo mismo, pero al momento de realizarlo en mysql workbench me da este error:

Comment: Executing:
ALTER TABLE `sys_fenix`.`alumnos` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `sys_fenix`.`alumnos` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez de hecho no, por que siguiendo el código actual daría este error `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: entonces puedes hacer un procedimiento almacenado que genere ese campo

Comment: Gracias, publique ya mi solucion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debido a que tratas de generar el `id` como `AUTO_INCREMENT` y ese atributo debe ser puesto en una columna la cual va a ser definida como `PRIMARY KEY` de la cual solo puede existir una

Dado lo anterior puedes dejar tu tabla `alumnos` modo siguiente

- `id` como `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`
- `rut_alumno` como `UNIQUE` el cual es un `CONSTRAINT` que asegura registros únicos para esa columna

Quedando de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE `alumnos` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rut_alumno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `edad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `clave` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_licencia` INT NULL,
  `id_region` INT NULL,
  `id_sucursal` INT NULL,
  `id_curso` INT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL);
```

**CREACIÓN DEL ÍNDICE**

Opcionalmente después de la creación de tu tabla, puedes crear un índice para la columna `rut_alumno` para indexar los datos de esta misma pues como son datos compuestos es decir letras y números las búsquedas se verán aceleradas por indexarlos

```
CREATE INDEX rut_alumnos ON alumnos (rut_alumno);
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

- `CREATE INDEX` Es la sentencia para crear el índice
- `rut_alumnos` Es el nombre que se le dará a este índice
- `ON alumnos` indica en que tabla se creará dicho índice
- `(rut_alumno)` indica la columna la cual se indexará

REFERENCIAS

- [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [CONSTRAINT UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

Gracias por la respuestas de todos y por la amabilidad de contestarme, ya pude solucionar el problema, y les doy otra manera de incluir el AUTO_INCREMENT sin necesidad que se convierta en PK:

```
CREATE TABLE `sys_fenix`.`alumnos` (
  `id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `rut_alumno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellido` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `edad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `clave` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_licencia` INT NULL,
  `id_region` INT NULL,
  `id_sucursal` INT NULL,
  `id_curso` INT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rut_alumno`),INDEX(`id`));
```

como se ve agregue al final que 'id' sea como indice (INDEX) y en la tabla le coloque simplemente AUTO_INCREMENT y problema resuelto

Comment: Recuerda por favor aceptar una respuesta, la que haya solucionado el problema